# What is that feeling one gets when they are about to sneeze?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

You know you have a sneeze coming, and you do that, *haah haaah*, the nose gets this odd feeling but the sneeze doesn't happen.

What's this feeling/thing called?

Comment: Interesting question. I think most people would know what you were talking about if you called it the "sneezing sensation", but I don't know of a specific name for it.

Comment: Tingly. At least, that's what I call it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say that you're feeling *[sneezy](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sneezy)*.

Comment: A million guesses .... Never would have thought of it..great answer.

Comment: I can't believe that's in the dictionary.  Great word.

Answer (score 4):

I believe that feeling is called a 'tickle'.

Comment: I had thought about it but asked to see if there was any specific word for this.

Answer (score 0):

I will venture 'sternutatory sensation'.

Comment: I would gladly upvote this if a reference is provided...

Comment: @SoylentGreen If you look at the Wiki entry for 'sneeze' you will see it is extensive. 'Sternutation' is the medical term for a sneeze. From there I took a step sideways to 'sternutatory', which exists as a word. Hence the experience of which you speak must be a 'sternutatory sensation'.